# How to migrate OpenCart to WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, migration, opencart

I have 15000 products and 200 categories which I want to transfer from opencart to my new store developed in woocommerce , I did reseach and I found  2 plugins `Cart2Cart` and `LiteExtension` but those are expensive for me and I dont want to use a paid plugins or service, is there any way or script or solution that I get open cart products and import in woocommerce?

I only want to import

- Products (SKU, PICTURE, VARIABLES, TAGS, ASSOCIATED CATEGORIES)
- Categories

I do not need customers or any other data

Please help.

Comment: In my subjective opinion, if your main business are e-commerce, so use e-commerce software like OpenCart or some similar. Wordpress with his plugin is not e-commerce software and are very limited.

Comment: that's a client requirement so i have to move products

Comment: Try this free plugin on WordPress.org: [Store to WooCommerce Migration Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextcart-woocommerce-migration/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have exported your products in CSV/XML, you can easily import your products into new WooCommerce store.

There is a free WooCommerce [product import extension plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) which will help you to do that very easily. [sample CSV](https://www.webtoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Product_WooCommerce_Sample_CSV.csv)

Answer (score 1):

A general way of moving the products and categories will be exporting them into an easily accessible format (csv, json, etc) and import them into your new webstore.

Opencart marketplace provides the extension for exporting your products, categories etc... and you can import them into csv format then you can use them to import into the woocommerce platform.

I will provide a link to the opencart extension which is actually free.

[Opencart: Import/Export Extension](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=17)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest direct database migration from Opencart to Woocommerce, which seems to be the cleanest way. There are tools outthere which can help you do this. This one is free, and made by a famous developer, check it out: [Migrate Shopping Carts to Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/litextension-data-migration-to-woocommerce/)

Answer (score 0):

When migrating from OpenCart to WooCommerce, you should consider some issues:

1. OpenCart uses Custom Options for product while WooCommerce uses Variations. In this case, I recommend you to install WooCommerce Product Extra Option plugin.
2. SEO meta title and meta description: this data is very important for your website's ranking, don't forget to migrate it. You could use Yoast SEO or Rank Math plugin to handle your SEO data in WooCommerce.

For your question about the migration tools, free plugins will not be able to afford the 2 issues above, pro versions would be better. But if you are looking for a migration tool that can cover the problems listed above, I recommend you to use this [OpenCart to WooCommerce](https://next-cart.com/product/opencart-to-woocommerce/) migration tool of Next-Cart. This is a really good migration software at a much more affordable price.